# UIDocumentPickerViewController - does not pick document

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following document picker, adapted from [here](https://gist.github.com/richo/61f308f5e4ba1fe7eefb8035aaa7817a), running on iOS device / simulator.

```
struct FilePickerController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var callback: (URL) -> ()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FilePickerController>) {
        // Update the controller
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        debugPrint("Making the picker")
        let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeText)], in: .open)
        
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        debugPrint("Setup the delegate \(context.coordinator)")
        
        return controller
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        var parent: FilePickerController
        
        init(_ pickerController: FilePickerController) {
            self.parent = pickerController
            debugPrint("Setup a parent")
            debugPrint("Callback: \(String(describing: parent.callback))")
        }
        
        func documentPicker(didPickDocumentsAt: [URL]) {
            debugPrint("Selected a document: \(didPickDocumentsAt[0])")
            parent.callback(didPickDocumentsAt[0])
        }
        
        func documentPickerWasCancelled() {
            debugPrint("Document picker was thrown away :(")
        }
        
        deinit {
            debugPrint("Coordinator going away")
        }
    }
}

struct FilePickerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FilePickerController(callback: filePicked)
    }
    
    func filePicked(_ url: URL) {
        debugPrint("Filename: \(url)")
    }
}
```

When running, the document picker correctly opens and I can select a text file. However, I get the following output in the console:

```
"Setup a parent"
"Callback: (Function)"
"Making the picker"
"Setup the delegate <_TtCV7EasyFPU20FilePickerController11Coordinator: 0x600003d41b60>"
2020-08-07 12:05:02.116936+0200 EasyFPU[53507:2766688] [Common] _BSMachError: port 6437; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2020-08-07 12:05:04.315792+0200 EasyFPU[53507:2790673] [DocumentManager] Failed to associate thumbnails for picked URL file:///Users/Ulrich/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC04A404-7456-4CD8-888B-49346927986C/data/Containers/Data/Application/64FDB970-1A0E-4E03-9FF7-AB089EDDCA98/Documents/8619BCA8-1186-4265-AE8E-AD82FA11E460.json with the Inbox copy file:///Users/Ulrich/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC04A404-7456-4CD8-888B-49346927986C/data/Containers/Data/Application/64FDB970-1A0E-4E03-9FF7-AB089EDDCA98/tmp/info.rueth.EasyFPU-Inbox/8619BCA8-1186-4265-AE8E-AD82FA11E460.json: Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000337f7e0 {Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Generation not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=Generation not found}}}
2020-08-07 12:05:06.232918+0200 EasyFPU[53507:2766688] [Common] _BSMachError: port 14e03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
"Coordinator going away"
```

The function `documentPicker` is never called. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function documentPicker is never called. Any ideas why?

Because you declared the delegate method wrong. You have

```
func documentPicker(didPickDocumentsAt: [URL]) {
```

It should be

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, 
      didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
```

Comment: And of course the other one is wrong too. Should be `func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController)`. Basically the docs tell you what to do, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate, and you didn’t do any of it. I’m surprised you didn’t get a compiler warning about this.